# how can i get a url helper for the contact us (contacts) page of my magento 1.9.2 site?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, toplinks

Hi I have sucessfully added a link to top links in the customer.xml file in my theme.

I added this code to `<reference name="top.links" />`

```
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts"><label>Contact Us</label><url helper="customer/getContactsUrl"/><title>Contact Us</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>60</position><liParams/><aParams>class="header_contactUs"</aParams></action>
```

the link just points to the main page of my website not to www.website.co.uk/english/contacts

I have tried to avoid using `<url helper="??" />`
and just use `<url>contacts</url>` but this does not prepend the word english to the target. And if I insert the word english it breaks for the german store (obviously).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. ty everybody who looked. You can lift the correct `<action method="addLink">` line from the footer where it already appears. I found it in contacts.xml and was able with a modicum of editing to get the style i wanted added as well.

for the record you should add the line

```
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled"><label>Contact Us</label><url>contacts</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>60</position><liParams/><aParams>class="header_contactUs"</aParams></action>
```

to the

```
<default>
<reference name="top.links">
                  <!!!!code goes here/>
</reference>
</default>
```

section of either your customer.xml file or your contacts.xml file (whichever seems more logical)